# Kentico - Password Protect Content

Tags: kentico

I have some set of documents and want to password protect them with one set of userid/password for each group of users. It's like this:

- All users in group 1 can access *domain.com/survey1/* with userid1/password1
- All users in group 2 can access *domain.com/survey2/* with userid2/password2
- etc....

Outside of Kentico, I can go to the webhosting control panel and apply password to any folders.

With Kentico (global admin privilege, no backend/server access) I'm not sure if this is possible and if yes, how to do it. Thanks for your input.

**Note:** I've tried creating a custom login page using the Logon Form webpart; set the destination URL for the Logon Form to a landing page that lists links to the docs; then added the mentioned docs as subpages; added new user (userid1/password1) through Users app and also under Properties/Security. But this didn't work as expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Michelle, basically you want a group of user share a single username/password combination, right? Which is basically a "group" of people all use a single "user" account in CMS.

So first you setup user account like user1/pw1, user2/pw2.

Then in you content tree, go to /survey1 > Properties > Security > set it to requirement authentication. Then add user1 to have READ permission. Do the same for other folders.

Then in a different browser session which you are not logged in, try to hit yoursite.com/survey1, it should redirect you to a login page, once you login with user1/pw1, it should route you back to /survey1.

If you have created your own login page like /mylogin.aspx, then go to Settings application > Settings > Security & Membership > Content > Website logon page URL, and add that ~/mylogin.aspx there, so when visitor is prompt for login, it will be that page.

Comment: Thank you Rui! Everythings worked as expected. Initially I thought each group of users required their own logon pages,but it turns out we only need one logon page (and leave blank the **_Default target URL_** in the Logon Form webpart)